# puppeteer waitForSelector not working when passing a string variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer and having problem with waitForSelector when passing a variable. However, it works fine when passing the string itself.

```
**// Not Working Code**
let subDomain =  '#yahya\\\\.infinitystudio\\\\.pk_lnkRemove' 

await page.waitForSelector(subDomain )
await Promise.all ([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    page.click(subDomain)
    ])`

**// Working Code**

`
await page.waitForSelector('#yahya\\.infinitystudio\\.pk_lnkRemove')
await Promise.all ([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    page.click('#yahya\\.infinitystudio\\.pk_lnkRemove')
    ])`

Any clue what is wrong in this.
```

Comment: Why are you using backslashes at all in this string? Pretty clearly, the string variable is different than the working code.

Comment: thats because the element id has . (fullstop) in it. If I dont use \\ in the working code, it does not work at all.

Comment: But why double the number of slashes for the variable version? ```\\\\``` is different than ```\\```. Whether you save it in a variable or not is irrelevant. You've changed the selector.

Comment: when I use only double \\ back slash, the output string contain single and thats obvious because its a escape sequence character. In order to have . in my string, I have to use \\ and in order to have \\ in string, I have to use \\\\.

Comment: below are the output from console of chrome.

console.log('my string contains \.')
my string contains .

console.log('my string contains \\.')
my string contains \.

console.log('my string contains \\\\.')
my string contains \\.

Comment: I don't follow. If ```\\``` works for the literal parameter, keep it that way for the variable as well. Adding a variable doesn't impact the string literal at all, so there should be no need to use ```\\\\```. Maybe show the selector/page you're working with so I can run code and verify.

Comment: <a id="admin.infinitystudio.pk_lnkRemove" class="btn btn-link" href="dodeldomainconfirm.html?domain=admin.infinitystudio.pk">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    Remove
                </a>

Comment: i need to catch this id "admin.infinitystudio.pk_lnkRemove"

Comment: Please [edit] the post to show that.

Comment: Did you try running the code with ```let subDomain =  '#yahya\\.infinitystudio\\.pk_lnkRemove'```? This should be the correct escape.

Comment: this works fine, but I need to concat a string... because the information is dynamic.
I get "yahya" and I have concat with ".infinitystudio.pk" (which is again from config) and than "_lnkRemove"

Comment: Just to give you a full background of the information. I want to delete a subdomain on CPanel of a website. So I login CPanel with username and password, Click on SubDomain link, search for subdomain that is coming from database  and in this case its "yahya" and than I search for the id by concatenating the subdomain and making it string that is required by puppeteer.

Comment: Can you show the concats? Even with concats, it'd still be ```\\```, not ```\\\\```. None of this seems "special" in any way. `const subDomain = '#yahya' + '\\.infinitystudio' + '\\.pk_lnkRemove'` should work just the same. Those 3 strings could be moved to separate variables, still the same.